# I need help changing the width of my navbar as well keeping it centered at the top of the page

Tags: css, bootswatch

I can't seem to figure out how to center & change the width of my whole navigation bar for my [website](http://megacoincasino.com/slots)

-I'm using the slate bootswatch theme

Comment: http://pastebin.com/u5CBcadE here is my bootstrap.css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default" style="
    width: 600px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 35%;
">
...............
  <div class="navbar-collapse collapse navbar-responsive-collapse" style="
    width: 500px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 10%;
">
```

Change the number to fix as you want, not really a good way but maybe you want to see

Comment: It kind of works but now my slot machine is touching the navigation bar?

Comment: <div class="game" style="
    margin-top: 50px;
">

Comment: Thank you for help. It seems to not stay in position when I zoom in or out.  Is their a simple fix for this?

Comment: I checked your website, it's OK when zoom in and out, so, what's the problem?

Comment: It's fixed but now when I go on mobile and  click the menu icon it won't retract back?

Comment: On PC , it work well, so the reason is your device browser,let try in another device, or another browser of your device

Comment: I used google chrome and tried safari on the iPhone5c & tried the galaxy s4 but when I press on the menu button it will not retract back after pressing it

Comment: $(".Games").attr('class','Games open') this to open
$(".Games").attr('class','Games') this to close
let try to implement when you click on game menu, and test on mobile

Answer (score 0):

You may have to add additional css to tweak the bootstrap css:

```
.navbar-nav{           
    display: inline-block;  
    float: none; 
} 

.navbar-collapse {
    text-align: center;
}
```

and remove the class `navbar-right` from the navigation `ul`

to change the width of each menu item, target the `.nav > li > a`

e.g., `.nav > li > a { width: 150px;}`